# Querying a strapi database by date with less than operator

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, strapi

```
module.exports = async () => {
  var d = new Date();
  var nd = Math.floor(d.getTime() / 1000);

  strapi.log.info(`the current utc date is: ${nd}`);

  //strapi.config.functions['mark_old_events']()

  const getEvents = async (nd) => {
    try {
      const events = await strapi.query("festival").find({
        _limit: 500,
        isParent: false,
        isActive: true,
        updated_at: `>= ${nd}`,
      });

      const ne = JSON.stringify(events[events.length - 1]);
      strapi.log.info(`There are ${events.length} events, ${ne}`);
      return events;
    } catch (err) {
      strapi.log.error("Error querying festivals", err);
    }
  };
```

I am trying to query the strapi data base for festivals with these parameters. The query runs withoout the `updated_at` parameter. The issue i am having is pulling festivals that are `updated_at` greater than or equal to today. Any suggestion on how to approach this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I see you were using `strapi.query` I assume you are using Strapi v3. In that case you shouldn't use `>=`, instead for that, you should use `_gt`/`_gte` and `_lt`/`_lte` attribute operators. In this particular case you should use the `_gte` like this:

```js
updated_at_gte: nd,
```

So you would do:

```js
const events = await strapi.query("festival").find({
  _limit: 500,
  isParent: false,
  isActive: true,
  updated_at_gte: nd,
});
```

In **Strapi v4** you would have to do:

```js
const events = await strapi.db.query("api:festival.festival").findMany({
  isParent: false,
  isActive: true,
  updated_at: {$gte: nd},
});
```

Source:

https://docs-v3.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#filters

https://forum.strapi.io/t/query-by-month-or-by-year-or-by-specific-day/3802/2